# migrating from log4j to logback (slf4j)

Tags: java, maven, logging, jar

I'm working on an app that uses log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.5.jar and trying to migrate to logback (weblogic to jboss migration). every class being used only imports slf4j, there is no log4j import in any of the classes. Does this basically mean that the migration should include no code change, just replace the jars in the build path from log4j to logback?

Also, the only log4j jar file I see after doing a search is log4j-over-slf4j.jar, should replacing that jar, alone, with a logback equivalent be enough?

I apologize, I cant include any source code, not allowed

Comment: Sounds like you are right on the money. If you already use slf4j for all your logging then all you need to do to swap the back end is remove the log4j-over-slf4j backend from the classpath and add logback. Obviously you need to add a `logback.xml` or `logback.groovy` logging config file too.

Comment: The cool thing with software (vs. bridges or houses) is that you can try things, and no one is hurt if it doesn't work. Why don't you try and see?

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses, I will try it. @JBNizet One issue with it is that its a huge application for work, and it will require a lot of work to try (there are currently other things being debugged with it at the moment)